# Where did I go wrong in this code?

Tags: java

A few of my classes aren't passing automated tests. Unfortunately, said tests do not provide any useful information about why they failed. Here is my code for a couple of the classes.  I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me where I went wrong. The comments should explain what each method is supposed to do.

```
public class CellPhone {
    protected String ownerName;

        public CellPhone(String owner) {
           ownerName = owner;


        }

    public String receiveCall(CellPhone sender) {
        // returns a String of the form:
        // owner's name " is receiving a call from " sender's name
        String receivingCall = ownerName + " is receiving a call from " + sender;

        return receivingCall;
    }

    public String call(CellPhone receiver) {
        // returns a String by using the receiver to invoke receiveCall
        // while passing in the current phone
        String invokingReceiveCall = receiver.receiveCall(receiver);

        return invokingReceiveCall;

    }
}
```

---

```
public class TextMessagingPhone extends CellPhone {
    private int availMessages;

    public TextMessagingPhone(String owner, int messageLimit) {
        // invokes the superclass constructor
        super(owner);
        // sets the new instance variable
        availMessages = messageLimit;
    }

    public TextMessagingPhone(String owner) {
        // invokes the other constructor of this class with 15 as the message limit
        this(owner, 15);
    }

    public String receiveText(TextMessagingPhone sender, String message) {
        // decreases the number of messages available to send
        availMessages--;

        // returns a String of the form:
        // owner's name " has received TEXT from " sender's name ":" message
        String receivedText = ownerName + " has received TEXT from " + sender + ":" + message;

        return receivedText;
    }

    public String sendText(TextMessagingPhone receiver, String message) {
        // decreases the number of messages available to send
        availMessages--;

        // returns a String by using the receiver to invoke receiveText
        // while passing in the current phone and the message
        String invokingReceiveText = receiver.receiveText(receiver, message);

        return invokingReceiveText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's hard to tell you what's wrong without info on what is failing. You mention that they fail tests... well.. what tests?

Comment: Have you considered assigning something to ownerName?

Comment: Can you post the tests that you are running and which ones are failing?

Comment: Is this homework?  You may wish to add the homework tag.  Anyway, your CellPhone class constructor doesn't initialize the ownerName field.

Comment: Automated tests are kind of worthless if they don't tell you what went wrong. Do you have any access to the tests? Or are these "tests" something your professor set up and he expects you to figure out the issues on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a phone makes a call, it passes the *receiver* as a parameter, so the receiver thinks it is receiving from itself. Also it never gets the name from the passed sender. Try:

```
public String receiveCall(CellPhone sender) {        
    // returns a String of the form:        
    // owner's name " is receiving a call from " sender's name        
    String receivingCall = ownerName + " is receiving a call from " + sender.getName();        
    return receivingCall;    
}

public String call(CellPhone receiver) {        
    // returns a String by using the receiver to invoke receiveCall        
    // while passing in the current phone        
    String invokingReceiveCall = receiver.receiveCall(this);        
    return invokingReceiveCall;    
}

public String getName() {
    return ownerName;
}
```

Comment: The same goes for the `TextMessagingPhone`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public CellPhone(String owner) {

        }
```

You don't assign anything to `ownerName`...

```
 public CellPhone(String owner) {
            ownerName = owner;
        }
```

Comment: nice catch, and maybe this is it

Comment: yeah my bad. i fixed that but that wasn't what was causing this to fail

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
        String receivingCall = ownerName + " is receiving a call from " + sender;
```

You are using "sender" which is an object in the string expression. Using sender.ownerName after making it public or defining getOwnerName and using it should work. This same mistake is repeated couple more times!